# How make work werkzeug / custom error pages with flask + Gevent-socketio

Tags: python, exception, flask, werkzeug, gevent-socketio

I have a flask + Gevent-socketio mini website. Is launched:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

@werkzeug.serving.run_with_reloader
def runServer():
    print 'Listening on %s...' % WEB_PORT
    ws = SocketIOServer(('0.0.0.0', WEB_PORT),
        SharedDataMiddleware(app, {}),
        resource="socket.io",
        policy_server=False)

    ws.serve_forever()
```

However, when a error happend in my views, it output

```
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">Internal Server Error</pre>
```

instead of show the werkzeug debugger. Also, my custom `@app.errorhandler(500)` is not called.

This happend on using Gevent-socketio, regular flask website works fine.

I wonder what is handling the error and canceling the default flask behavior...

Answer (score 2):

I've recently solved this, Werkzeug debuggger can be modified to work with socket.io namespaces (and auto-reloading will also work), see here and enjoy:

https://github.com/aldanor/SocketIO-Flask-Debug

Answer (score 1):

To see werkzeug debugger you must serve all http request by default server with standart middleware stack.

But you launched separate SocketIOServer for serve websockets requests.

[example for flask and gevent_socketio usage](https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/blob/master/examples/flask_chat/chat.py)

Comment: I do that but get hit by the error: KeyError: 'socketio'. I think was related to https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/issues/63 so I rollback to several socket.io clients, but not work. However, it's work if I left it as before. So using this solution get the error and socket io not work.